# Send data securely from C# to a MySQL database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 3D to create a simple game. I am generating some data in the client and i would like to save the data in a MySQL database.

I am currently sending the data from the C# Script to a PHP Interface that stores the data in a MySQL database.

But there are too many security gaps:

- The apk-file is readable
- User can read the methods and functions. He could mainpulate data and send it to the php-file

I have no idea, how i can solve this problem.

If i am encrypt the information, the user can read the apk-file and can see, how i encrypt the information. And see there, he could maipulate data. :D

I hope someone can give me some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a **JSON** text to **PHP** 
Inside your **PHP** use this:

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

$ID= $json_obj->ID;

//Insert MYSQL Codes
```

This is will decode the JSON you have sent from your C# and the rest is up to you